# redis-cli CLUSTER NODES command shows different info on different nodes after CLUSTER RESET

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, redis-cluster

We have a Redis Cluster with 3 machines with Master+Slave on each machine ( Amazon Cloud envs).
The order is [M1,S3] [M2,S1] [M3,S2]

After restart of one machine, for example [M2,S1], the CLUSTER NODES command shows different info. I don't understand how it is possible.

For example:
./redis-cli -h 10.20.21.59 -p 7000 CLUSTER NODES command shows following:

bba828ee8151f5addb0cb3d3bf91db559837c13f 10.20.21.59:7000 myself,master - 0 0 3 connected

BUT ./redis-cli -h 10.20.21.59 -p 7001 CLUSTER NODES command shows completely different thing:

d7d45ad6d12dfe65dff2867be05eef678ef72f69 10.20.21.44:7000 slave de0ecb56f8cd28fc99807d51851bc735887e5a0a 0 1460988751963 6 connected
de0ecb56f8cd28fc99807d51851bc735887e5a0a 10.20.21.113:7001 master - 0 1460988751462 6 connected 0-5461
c034167f1ec790f4a5fdb28bb91843b03cbc77a0 10.20.21.113:7000 master - 0 1460988750960 2 connected 5462-10922
9a74b8c329437cb845d409b34222a3adbe6146d2 10.20.21.44:7001 slave bba828ee8151f5addb0cb3d3bf91db559837c13f 0 1460988752463 4 connected
69243875fc4a0dea0a95d559fbc8be8e8550c25f 10.20.21.59:7001 myself,slave c034167f1ec790f4a5fdb28bb91843b03cbc77a0 0 0 5 connected
bba828ee8151f5addb0cb3d3bf91db559837c13f 10.20.21.59:7000 master - 0 1460988752964 3 connected 10923-16383

Anybody can explain what is happening?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of the "cluster info" command in M2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just the way `CLUSTER RESET` command works. So it is a normal behavior.